# update labels after combo box index changed

Tags: c#, winforms

in my application i am get all the network adapters
when i am change the adapter inside my combo box (in case my machine has more than one...) 
combo-box_SelectedIndexChanged function call my function and received the adapters, my problem is that after the combo box index changed my function didn't update my labels.

in this line: `IEnumerable<NetworkAdapter> add = adapter.getAdapterInfo();` i am received collection of my adapters and every adapter has it's own properties (name, id, speed, ip...)

```
private void comboBoxAdaptersWindow_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combobox = sender as ComboBox;
    NetworkAdapter selectedNic = combobox.SelectedItem as NetworkAdapter;
    UpdateForm(selectedNic);
}


private void UpdateForm(NetworkAdapter adapter)
{
    IEnumerable<NetworkAdapter> add = adapter.getAdapterInfo();
    List<NetworkAdapter> adaptersList = add.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < adaptersList.Count; i++) //update my labels
    {
        lblName2.Text = adaptersList[i]._name;
        lblId2.Text = adaptersList[i]._id;
        lblInterfaceType2.Text = adaptersList[i]._networkInterfaceType;
        lblIPv4Address2.Text = adaptersList[i]._ipAddress;
        lblDefaultGateway2.Text = adaptersList[i]._gatewayIpAddress;
        lblMacAddress2.Text = adaptersList[i]._macAddress;
        lblSpeed2.Text = adaptersList[i]._speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code sample is illogical as written. Your UpdateForm class goes through and sets the same labels to i different values. The result is that your labels will hold the values of adaptersList[adaptersList.Count-1]. It is possible that those values are not the values you expect or that is not the correct behavior. How would you like this to behave?

Comment: can i have code sample how to do it ?

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to explain what you want to appear in the labels and how many labels you have. It's not clear what the goal of this method from what you've said. Can you give us a sample of your input data and what you want your GUI to look like afterwards? Then, we can help you make the code work right.

Comment: OK i saw my problem. i defined variable that hold the combo box index and send it to UpdateForm and now it's works